# installing valgrind in ssh client

Tags: unix

I am new in Unix, can somebody kind to tell me how to install valgrind in ssh client so that I can use valgrind command in my sunfire account?

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify what exactly you're trying to do? I'm not sure if you want to use valgrind to analyze the ssh client, or ssh to a machine and then run valgrind.

Comment: I want to ssh to my sunfire account and use valgrind command to check memory leak of c programs, however, there is no valgrind command in sunfire, so what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of what kind of unix it is; it depend also of your rights on the server.

If you're root, you can use for example under debian `sudo apt-get install valgrind`.

If you're not root, you'll have to dowload the sources, compile them, and then use valgrind from your own installation.